# Azure VM: OS disk size

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

After creating a Windows Server Virtual Machine in Azure I noticed that the OS disk (C: drive) is only 30GB in size.

My impression was that all new VMs have 127GB OS disk size. ([Expand the OS drive of a Windows VM in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk))

Could someone clarify please?

**Edit**

Also, I was creating a VM using my MSDN subscription - could that be the cause of this?

**Edit 2**

I managed to increase the OS drive size by running the following (as described in linked article above). Then I had to resize the disk inside the OS.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName 'my-subscription-name'
$rgName = 'my-resource-group-name'
$vmName = 'my-vm-name'
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName
# Set the size to whatever is needed.
$vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.DiskSizeGB = 1023
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VM $vm
Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName
```

Comment: Were you using the "Classic" Azure management portal or API or the new "Resource Manager" portal or API?

Comment: I was using portal.azure.com to login in to Azure.

Comment: Your'e sure it was Windows and not Linux? Windows VMs get 127GB OS disks, Linux have 30GB OS disks.

Comment: It was Windows Server 2016, I RDPed into it afterwards to check disk size.

Comment: FYI I saw the same results just now, with both managed and non-managed disks. I cannot explain this. Maybe open a support ticket? (unfortunately this particular question is off-topic for Stackoverflow, since there's no programming-related issue). Also note: This has nothing to do with the fact you're using an MSDN subscription.

Comment: No, I test in my lab. Windows Server 2012 also has a 30GB OS disk. I think Azure has some updates about it.

Comment: I think that @Walter-MSFT should bring some light into this issue, based on his username sufix... :)

Comment: What is your OS disk? Managed disk or ummanged disk?

Comment: Hi, do you resize your VM OS disk successful?

Comment: I used unmanaged disks. I successfully resized the disk using PowerShell script above (and then inside Windows as well). My OS disk is now 200GB.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, saw that yesterday. 
A way to circumvent this for the moment: I am using ARM to create the VMs, and now you can specify the disk size (to 60GB or 200GB, whatever you want), but the actual C partition is only 30GB. You need to go to Computer Management and expand the size of the C partition to occupy the entire disk.
Also, if using ARM for provisioning, you could use the previous SKU version of the Windows 2012 R2 / Windows 2016 OS image.
Hope that helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

The disk size has been changed from 127GB to 30GB by Microsoft yesterday. But that size is way too small. Once you install some applications your disk is full. It has to do with the way managed disks are invoiced. Allocated space instead of used space.

Solution:

1. shutdown VM
2. change size of OS disk
3. start VM
4. extend volume in disk management

Microsoft did the change without informing their clients, changing documentation,... waiting for news from the account manager but that is the info I got from technical contact.

Answer (score 0):

By default a temporary vhd is created for temporary files,
so we need to add a disk to store the os... 
the default second disk is automatically added for the Os
(for example in A1 basic, the temp disk is 40 Gb, and the second disk is 127 Gb)
this extra second disk need to be calculated for price estimation (it should be there by default in the calculator)
Frederic.